# Django only loads the first static file in a template

Tags: python, html, django

As the title says, only the first static file in a Django template is loaded.

Here is the offending code:

```
{% load staticfiles %}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{% block title %}{% endblock title %}</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'global/css/grid.css' %}" media="screen" title="grid" charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'global/css/style.css' %}" media="screen" title="main" charset="utf-8">
    </head>
```

I have 'global' set up correctly in my STATICFILES_DIRS, both 'grid.css' and 'style.css' exist in that directory, and both styles do not conflict.

But only 'grid.css' loads when I render a page with the above code in it.

When I check inspect element in chrome, *both links are displayed/rendered correctly*:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="global/css/grid.css" media="screen" title="grid" charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="global/css/style.css" media="screen" title="main" charset="utf-8">
```

But when I check the 'Sources' of chromes dev tools it shows the folder 'static/global/css', and within it *only* grid.css is displayed. So Django is not delivering style.css in the response.

I know that style.css works, when I comment out the line that loads grid.css, style.css *does* load.

So again, it seems that only the first static file that is requested in a template is delivered in the response.

Comment: so if you change the order of the css files, it's again the first one which will load?

Comment: Yes, if I switch grid.css and style.css in the above code, then style.css will load and grid.css will not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the HTML attribute  'title'. When that is set on a stylesheet link, then that stylesheet will become the 'prefered' stylesheet, and all others will be ignored. I got rid of the title attributes and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think this is from Django, as far as my knowledge django does not do that.

Clear your cache and try again. Maybe your first CSS file might have been loaded from cache and second file might not be cached earlier.

If both files are not loaded after clearing cache, then there is a mistake in your static file configuration.

If the first CSS comes even after clearing the cache, check the Network Tab in Google Chrome. See where the request goes, and see the response received. Check whether the response comes as the file or 404 or 503 and debug accordingly.

Comment: I'm getting a 304 for both staticfiles ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It means that both of your files are loading from cache .You can force reloading in your browser by checking "Disable cache" in your browser's dev tools (network tab -> disable cache). Then reload the page without closing the Dev Tools in chrome. Because closing it will enable cache. Now you should get 200 as response status for both files.

Comment: I did that, I'm getting 200 responses now. But still, only the first static file in the template is being returned

Comment: If you get 200 for both files, it mean that the file is returned to your browser successfully. You can check contents of the file in Response tab in the if you click that File name in the Network tab.

Comment: Strange, both files do appear in the network tab, with their content. But still, only the first static file appears in the Sources tab and is actually rendered on the page

Comment: Then this does not seem to be an issue with Django. Right click the page and click `View Page Source` and check whether both the files in `href="global/css/grid.css and href="global/css/style.css"`  are clickable. And then check both the link redirects to the specified file location. If yes then everything works fine.

Comment: Welp, those files are showing up correctly.
I'll try to find another source of the problem.
Thanks for staying around so long to help :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. If you feel your question has been answered, feel free to mark the answer as the accepted answer and upvote the answer and comments.